# Erro de sintaxe (PHP)

Tags: php

Estou criando um PHP para listar os arquivos de uma pasta e adicionei um estilo nele. Não sei o que está dando de errado, então, por favor me ajudem. Na página do meu servidor aparece erro na linha 26.

```
<?php

// diretorio dos pdf's
$dir = "./ebooks";

// ediretorio
$dh = opendir($dir);

// loop que busca todos os arquivos até que não encontre mais nada
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
// verificando se o arquivo é .pdf
if (substr($filename,-4) == ".pdf") {
// mostra o nome e o link do arquivo
echo "<a href=\"$filename\">$filename</a><br>";
?>
<style>
.blue
{
    background-color: #33383E;
    color: #C7C8C8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #14161A;
}
</style>
}
?>
```

Comment: Você nunca fecha o while

Comment: Nem o if. E fecha o php no final sem ter reaberto

Comment: Linha 26 é erro fantasma, pq seu código só tem 25 linhas!! O que deveria aparecer é:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in ........   line 25

Answer (score 1):

Cara não deve ter reparado mas no trecho

```
// loop que busca todos os arquivos até que não encontre mais nada
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
// verificando se o arquivo é .pdf
if (substr($filename,-4) == ".pdf") {
// mostra o nome e o link do arquivo
echo "<a href=\"$filename\">$filename</a><br>";
```

Você não fechou as chaves nem do while nem do if.
Olhe a maneira correta

```
// loop que busca todos os arquivos até que não encontre mais nada
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    // verificando se o arquivo é .pdf
    if (substr($filename,-4) == ".pdf") {
    // mostra o nome e o link do arquivo
        echo "<a href=\"$filename\">$filename</a><br>";
    }
}
?>
```

E nas últimas linhas do código existem uma chave e um fechamento da tag php a mais.

```
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alem das falhas apontadas nos comentários do nosso amigo  **bfavaretto** e a resposta dada pelo nosso novo amigo **Pablo Lauro da Silva**, há que se corrigir o link do arquivo na linha:

`echo "<a href=\"$filename\">$filename</a><br>";`

O correto é incluir a variável $dir para não se deparar com **pagina não encontrada**

`echo "<a href=\"$dir/$filename\">$filename</a><br>";`

Código completo e corrigido

```
<style>
.blue
{
    background-color: #33383E;
    color: #C7C8C8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #14161A;
}
</style>

<?php
// diretorio dos pdf's
$dir = "./ebooks";

// ediretorio
$dh = opendir($dir);

// loop que busca todos os arquivos até que não encontre mais nada
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    // verificando se o arquivo é .pdf
    if (substr($filename,-4) == ".pdf") {
    // mostra o nome e o link do arquivo
        echo "<a href=\"$dir/$filename\">$filename</a><br>";
    }
}
?>
```